# How to concatenate strings in Python using Format?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

I want to send dynamic data in my Payload,

```
payload = "{\r\n \"name\": \"{0}\",\r\n \"id\":\"{1}\"}".format(1,2)
*** KeyError: '\r\n "name"'
```

But when i try to add static value it's working fine :

`payload = "{\r\n \"name\": \"just\",\r\n \"id\":\"32\"}"`

How can i add dynamic data on it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that when you use `format()`, the brace character is special (because of `{0}`) and needs to be escaped by doubling the brace that is not special:

```
>>> payload = "{{\r\n \"name\": \"{0}\",\r\n \"id\":\"{1}\"}}".format("just",32)
>>> payload
'{\r\n "name": "just",\r\n "id":"32"}'
```

Answer (score 3):

It's because of the first and last brackets.

You have to escape `{` and `}`.

```
"{{\r\n \"name\": \"{}\",\r\n \"id\":\"{}\"}}".format(1,2)
```

Comment: I would guess the downvote might be because although you answered the question you should also have advised them against using string formatting at all to produce JSON.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of manipulating the JSON in string use the JSON module.

**Ex:**

```
import json
payload = {"name": '',"id":''}
payload["name"] = 1
payload["id"] = 2

payload = json.dumps(payload)
print( payload )
print( type(payload) )
```

**Output:**

```
{"name": 1, "id": 2}
<type 'str'>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the { and } that you are using. You should double them:

```
payload = "{{\r\n \"name\": \"{0}\",\r\n \"id\":\"{1}\"}}".format(1,2)
```